# render/execute jasvscript code (which is in a php string) inside virtuemart JDispatcher eg: plgVmConfirmedOrder

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery, virtuemart

I want to render/execute some javascript code written inside virtuemart
JDispatcher  eg: plgVmConfirmedOrder

eg:

```
$script='console.log("this is dummy script");jQuery.ajax({url:'',type:'post',success:function(){console.log("task has been done")}})';

function plgVmConfirmedOrder(VirtuemartCart $cart,$order){
      $document=JFactory::getDocument();
      $document->addScriptDeclaartion($script);// this is not working
      How to do?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your javascript properly.

```
$script='console.log("this is dummy script");jQuery.ajax({url:\'\',type:\'post\',success:function(){console.log("task has been done")}})';
```

And, you misspelt declaration

```
$document->addScriptDeclaartion($script);
```

And I presume you have your vm plugin installed and switched on and working.  If you're not sure if your event is firing then change your code to:

```
function plgVmConfirmedOrder(VirtuemartCart $cart,$order){
    echo "confirm order event fired";
    die();
}
```

If that doesn't work then your problem is different from dealing with js.